# How to find an integral representation of $ \frac{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{4x}{(1-x)^2}\right)}{2\sqrt{x^2-6x+1}} $

Tags: integration, real-numbers

I was trying to find an integral representation of the below function in respect to a different variable that allows me to manipulate the variable $ x $ easier :

$$ f(x) = \frac{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{4x}{(1-x)^2}\right)}{2\sqrt{x^2-6x+1}} $$

I noticed two things

1- $ \frac{d}{dx} \,  sin^{-1}\left(\frac{4x}{(1-x)^2}\right) = \frac{-4}{(x-1)\sqrt{x^2-6x+1}}$ for  $x>0$

2- $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{(z+a)(z+b)}} = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{(t-a)(b-t)}}\frac{1}{t+z} dt $

as such I can write

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-6x+1}}=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-2\sqrt{2}-3}^{2\sqrt{2}-3} \,\frac{1}{\sqrt{-t^2-6t-1}} \frac{1}{t+x} \,dt \tag{1}\label{1} $$

and so using the derivative of the inverse sine and its logarithmic definition i got

$$sin^{-1}\left(\frac{4x}{(1-x)^2}\right)= 2i \, ln(x-1) -\frac{4}{\pi}\int_{-2\sqrt{2}-3}^{2\sqrt{2}-3} \frac{ln(t+x)}{\sqrt{-t^2-6t-1}} \frac{1}{t+1} \,dt$$

and so

$$ \frac{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{4x}{(1-x)^2}\right)}{2\sqrt{x^2-6x+1}}=$$

$$\scriptsize{\frac{i}{\pi}\int_{-2\sqrt{2}-3}^{2\sqrt{2}-3}\frac{\ln(x-1)}{\sqrt{-t^2-6t-1}} \frac{1}{t+x} dt - \frac{2}{\pi^2}\left(\int_{-2\sqrt{2}-3}^{2\sqrt{2}-3} \,\frac{1}{\sqrt{-w^2-6w-1}} \frac{1}{w+x} dw\right)\left(\int_{-2\sqrt{2}-3}^{2\sqrt{2}-3} \frac{ln(t+x)}{\sqrt{-t^2-6t-1}} \frac{1}{t+1} dt\right)}$$

However, from this point on, I am quite lost as I don't know how to deal with the double integral as well as feeling that I have taken an unnecessarily difficult path. I was hoping to come up with a result similar to $(1)$ where everything is inside the integral.

Question : How can I come up with an integral representation for the function $f(x)$ (if there exists one) which is as similar as possible in format to result $(1)$ ?

Thank you kindly for your help and time.

Comment: $$\int_x \frac{2 (x-3) \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{4 x}{1-x^2}\right)+\frac{8 \left(x^2+1\right)
   \left(x^2-6 x+1\right)}{\left(x^2-1\right)^2 \sqrt{\frac{x^4-18
   x^2+1}{\left(x^2-1\right)^2}}}}{4 \sqrt{x^2-6 x+1}} dx$$ as per mathematica

Comment: @SagarM I apologize if i was not being clear enough , i was trying to find a representation in which the variable x is not being integrated , but rather another variable   like in result $(1)$

Comment: Apologies, I was the one to not read the problem carefully